# Increase max speaker volume in KDE 5 without installing additional software

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 18.04, volume-control, kde5

I am running **Kubuntu 18.04 LTS**. As the title says, is there any way to increase the **max speaker volume beyond 100%** in KDE 5 without installing additional software like Kmix, Veromix, etc.?

In Gnome and Unity, the volume could be increased beyond 100% through the default System Settings which was very useful.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible by accessing the **Audio Volume** widget's settings.

- Right-click the Audio Volume widget and open settings. [image: Audio Volume Settings]
- Open the General Tab.
- Change *max volume* and *volume step* as per your needs.
- That's it. Now, increasing volume through the volume keys lets you reach volume levels greater than 100%.
  [image: img]

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of KDE Plasma (~ version 5.17), this option exists in Volume manager itself, as a checkbox at the bottom named "Raise Maximum Volume", allows volume upto 150%.

[image: Plasma Volume Manager]